# Display Multiple Selected Checked Values from a CheckBox

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I have put together together a list of items in an HTML file and each time I check an item in the list I want it to appear where it says "Filter will display here" as a button" I've run a console.log over the js code and it says: "item not checked."

```js
const headerTag = document.querySelector('.header-tag');
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox li')

const listItems = [...list];

for(let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
      if(listItems.checked === true) {
        console.log('item checked');
      } else {
        console.log('item not checked');
      }
}
```

```css
.header-tag {
    display: contents;
}
```

```html
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header-tag">
    <p class="header-tag">Filter will display here</p>
  <ul class="checkbox">
    <li> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" class="item-list">Natural Systems
    </li>
    <li> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" class="item-list">Sustainability Integration 
    </li>
    <li> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" class="item-list">Social Systems
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

<script src='script.js'></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we set up an event listener when the DOM load (window.onload) and each time a checkbox is clicked, we take stock of all the checked boxes, grabbing their `parentNode.innerText` for the display. I also had to change the className you had for the outer container div (it had the same class as the tag where you wanted to display the checked items).

```js
const headerTag = document.querySelector('.header-tag');
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox li')


window.onload = function() {
  let cb = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  for (let x = 0; x < cb.length; x++) {
    cb[x].addEventListener('change', onCBChange)
  }
}

const onCBChange = (event) => {
  let l = [];
  let ck = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  for (let x = 0; x < ck.length; x++) {
    l.push(ck[x].parentNode.innerText)
  }
  headerTag.innerHTML = l.join(", ");
}
```

```css
.header-tag {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-tag-container">
    <p class="header-tag">Filter will display here</p>
    <ul class="checkbox">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" class="item-list">Natural Systems
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" class="item-list">Sustainability Integration
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" class="item-list">Social Systems
      </li>
    </ul>
</body>

<script src='script.js'></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your if condition is wrong.

1. In the loop you are not changing the counter of items.
2. Also, checkbox is the child control of li.

So, your if condition should be like this

```
if(listItems[i].children[0].checked === true) {
            console.log('item checked');
          } else {
            console.log('item not checked');
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, you can use the `event.target` and get the `nextSibling.nodeValue`. Use conditional to see if `e.target.checked && arr.includes(e.target.nextSibling.nodeValue)` then we push into an array. Second conditional to remove deselected items using ***index*** and ***splice*** `index = arr.indexOf(e.target.nextSibling.nodeValue)`. To display we set `displayEl.textContent = arr.join('- ')`

```js
const headerTag = document.querySelector('p.header-tag');
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox li input')
const arr = []

function getSelected(e) {
  if (e.target.checked && !arr.includes(e.target.nextSibling.nodeValue)) {
    arr.push(e.target.nextSibling.nodeValue)
  }
  if (!e.target.checked) {
    arr.indexOf(e.target.nextSibling.nodeValue) > -1 ?
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(e.target.nextSibling.nodeValue), 1):null
  }
  return headerTag.textContent = arr.join('- ')
}

list.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('change', getSelected)
})
```

```css
.header-tag {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-tag">
    <p class="header-tag">Filter will display here</p>
    <ul class="checkbox">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" class="item-list">Natural Systems
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" class="item-list">Sustainability Integration
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" class="item-list">Social Systems
      </li>
    </ul>
</body>

<script src='script.js'></script>

</html>
```